# InvalidCastException for nullable Datetime Column in C#

Tags: c#

Forgive me as this is probably a basic question to ask but I inherited a C# application and I'm just starting to get a feel for C#. The below code is throwing an InvalidCastException. I assume since the value is null. I can't quite figure out how to rewrite this to be nullable. I already tried System.DateTime? in the two areas:

```
            public System.DateTime EndOfDayDate {
                get {
                    try {
                        return ((global::System.DateTime)(this[this.tableFacility.EndOfDayDateColumn]));
                    }
                    catch (global::System.InvalidCastException e) {
                        throw new global::System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column \'EndOfDayDate\' in table \'Facility\' is DBNull.", e);
                    }
                }
                set {
                    this[this.tableFacility.EndOfDayDateColumn] = value;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Treat the value as an object so you can test for null and if not null then cast to a DateTime.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do since I posted the question but I'm struggling with the syntax. Any chance you can point me in the correct direction?

Comment: This seemed to work, is this right? ```if (this[this.tableFacility.EndOfDayDateColumn] == System.DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            return null;
                        }```

Comment: You have to change the return type of method from System.DateTime to object to be able to return a null.  What I sometimes do is return new DateTime() (which is 1/1/1) so I can return a DateTime.  Then check for a realistic date like > 1/1/2000.